# Keep open socket connection Perl

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I created a Perl script that opens a new socket on my server.
When I connect with telnet to the socket and I write (and receive) something, the connection closes.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(Listen    => 5,
                                 LocalAddr => 'localhost',
                                 LocalPort => 9000,
                                 Reuse => 1,
                                 Proto     => 'tcp');
die "Socket not created $!\n" unless $sock;
print "Server waiting for connections\n";
while(1)
{
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $sock->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "Connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    my $data = "";
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
    chomp($data);
    print "Data: $data\n";

    # write response data to the connected client
    my $dataok = "OK";
    $client_socket->send("$dataok\n");
    $client_socket->send("$data\n");
    if($data == 500){
        close($sock);
        exit(); 
    }
    elsif($data eq "Close\r") {
        close($sock);
        exit();
    }
}
```

My telnet session:

```
telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
e //(Sent)
e //(Received)
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Why does my script close the connection?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not the problem, but you need to use `eq`, not `==` when your data contains non-numerical characters.

Comment: Yes, I know. I fixed it on my machine.

Comment: Have you any suggestion to solve my problem? @simbabque

Comment: Please [edit] and update the question then. Always show us your real code, so you're not wasting someone's time on a problem that isn't one ;)

Comment: After the accept you read something, write something and then your block inside the loop is done. This means the client file descriptor gets out of scope which closes the socket. If you want to read+write multiple times on the same connection you have to make a loop around this reading and writing.

Comment: Thanks to @SteffenUllrich. It worked!

Comment: Why the hell do you need to open a socket in PERL

Comment: @GiovanniZaccaria Sometimes you have to make ends meet with the tools you have been given…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a loop in my code and it worked!
Thanks to @simbabque and @SteffenUllrich.

```
    # waiting for a new client connection
    my $client_socket = $sock->accept();

    # get information about a newly connected client
    my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
    my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
    print "Connection from $client_address:$client_port\n";

    # read up to 1024 characters from the connected client
    while(1){
        my $data = "";
        $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
        chomp($data);
        print "Data: $data\n";

        # write response data to the connected client
        my $dataok = "OK";
        $client_socket->send("$dataok\n");
        $client_socket->send("$data\n");
        if($data == 500){
            close($sock);
            exit(); 
        }
        elsif($data eq "Close\r") {
            close($sock);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The outer loop is not needed, as you specifically `exit` the program, so it will only ever make one connection.